# Travelling fro Cebu, Philippines to Toronto, Canada via Narita/Haneda, Japan with 2 check-in luggage

Tags: air-canada, philippine-airlines

I will be traveling with 2 check-in luggage from Cebu Philippines to Toronto Canada via Narita / Haneda Japan with only 4 hours layover between Narita and Haneda transfer and Haneda/Toronto departure. Do I have enough time?`

Answer (score 2):

No one knows.

I give it about a 50/50 chance but it depends on a lot of unpredictable factors and there is no room for error or delays. Personally, I would try to change this booking.

You need to

1. Get off the plane to the baggage hall Collect your bags
2. Clear Japan customs and immigration (make sure you have a proper entry authorization/visa for Japan)
3. Carry your bags to whatever means of transport you have chosen. (Limo, cap, bus, train)
4. Find/wait for your transport
5. Transit to Haneda
6. Arrive at the air Canada check-in/bag drop a minimum of 60 minutes before departure.
7. Go through security and immigration and be a the gate at least 15 minutes before departure

Transit time alone is 60-100 minutes depending on means of transport and time of day.

Good resources:

- https://pretraveller.com/narita-airport-nrt-to-haneda-airport-hnd-transfer/#4_Taxi_or_Uber_from_Narita_NRT_to_Haneda_Airport_HND
- https://www.aircanada.com/us/en/aco/home/plan/check-in-information/check-in-and-boarding-times.html